# how to do custom path planning for autonomous navigation in ROS?

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, path-planning, custom-message

my autonomous navigation can work on my current map , but now i want to do a  simple **custom path planning** together with some actions , such as ,

-**taking a snapshot using the camera**

-**stopping**

-**turning the robot to the left and turning it back to the right to continue its path**

i have done research and saw that a simple XML file can do the job , i tried some codes but i couldnt do it , can anyone help me , appreciate it. Can i do the actions with only a XML config file

im kinda new to ROS and dont have much time left to finish the project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use [moveit](https://moveit.ros.org/) and integrate your robot with Moveit. It might make motion planning a lot easier for you.